# Best practice for using different implementations of data fetching code in React/Next.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Coming from a .Net/C# background, a common pattern there is inversion of control/dependency injection, where we design an interface and then one or more classes that implement that interface. The various other classes that make up the app take in the interfaces that they need to do their job, and make use of the provided methods without worrying about internal implementation. It's then up to the app configuration to determine which one of the interface implementations should be used. This allows the same interface for things like CRUD operations on an API vs. a database, a file, etc.

To give a concrete example of what I'm trying to achieve in the Next.js world:

Let's say I have a todo app with a useTodos() custom hook that returns todos, and an api/getTodos.ts endpoint that also returns todos. Both the hook and the endpoint have in common that they both "get todos" from some data source and return them.

I want the ability to provide a common interface for getTodos() and provide several different implementations for it. And then a central point where I can control which part of the app uses which implementation. For example getTodos() could have the following implementations:

- Calls an API
- Query Supabase
- Query MySQL
- Query local storage
- Read from a local file

I can then centrally define that the useTodos() hook uses the getTodos() that calls an API, and the api/getTodos.ts uses the getTodos() that queries Supabase. When we decide Supabase is no longer for us and we move to MySQL, I don't need to hunt down all the places where I'm fetching data, instead I just change my central configuration to use the new MySQL implementation.

I'm not looking for a 1:1 imitation of .Net IoC patterns using some obscure library but rather for how this sort of stuff is routinely done in the JS/TS/React/Next.js world. I'm also using 100% functional programming so I'm not looking for solutions that involve classes.

Thank you for reading this far!

Comment: This should be achievable with a Context reasonably high in your component tree, you can use it to define all your retrieval functions you want to use in your hooks. If you don't mix and match sources (i.e. either All of A or All of B not a combination of both) you can easily make wrapping provider components around the context that provide the defaults for each source to the context.

Comment: @JacobSmit But what about the API route in a Next.js app? I would like to go one step higher and have a mechanism that applies to both the client side and the server side.

Comment: I am unsure of your use case. A mechanism that applies to both wouldn't be able to do local storage and a local file wouldn't be the same for server and client. "And then a central point where I can control which part of the app uses which implementation" Does this mean selecting which data type comes from which data source or do different parts of your solution use different data sources for the same data type?

Comment: You're right, it's not a realistic use case for the reasons you mention. I think something more realistic is to actually having this IoC pattern on the server side only, to support the use case of easily switching from one data source to another. Are you aware of a pattern in a node environment?